# IOS: release viewcontroller in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have this code to open a view controller with storyboard

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    secondViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
[self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
```

and it work fine, but when I remove it I want release secondViewController

```
[secondViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

and for release it??? there isn't an alloc when I call secondViewController...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` returns an `autoreleased` object. You don't have to release it. When you remove its `view` from its `superview` it will be released. If you are using `ARC` this question shouldn't be asked at all...

Comment: Cool, then you are okay. No need to release.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ARC. Just write `secondViewController = nil;`. It should be released automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's important to make the distinction between your visual UIView instance and the UIViewController instance. The `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` call returns a view controller object that has a UIView property (the UIViewController doesn't need to be explicitly released as it is an autoreleased instance) - this **UIView** is what's being added to a superview and it's also being retained by it, as long as it is indeed a subview of some view. Once you remove that view from the superview and provided you're using ARC, the view should be released unless you're holding a strong reference to it's UIViewController, in that case just assigning the UIViewController property a nil value will take care of it. If ARC is not used, you need to call "release" only if you explicitly retained the view **controller** (not the view)